# How to make a take a circle out of a shader?

Tags: glsl, shader, game-engine, fragment-shader

I'm working on a game using GLSL shaders

I'm using Go with the library Pixel, it's a 2d game and there's no "camera" (I've had people suggest using a second camera to achieve this)

My current shader is just a basic grayscale shader

```
#version 330 core
in vec2  vTexCoords;
out vec4 fragColor;
uniform vec4 uTexBounds;
uniform sampler2D uTexture;
void main() {
    // Get our current screen coordinate
    vec2 t = (vTexCoords - uTexBounds.xy) / uTexBounds.zw;
    // Sum our 3 color channels
    float sum  = texture(uTexture, t).r;
        sum += texture(uTexture, t).g;
        sum += texture(uTexture, t).b;
    // Divide by 3, and set the output to the result
    vec4 color = vec4( sum/3, sum/3, sum/3, 1.0);
    fragColor = color;
}
```

I want to take out a circle of the shader to show the color of objects almost like light is shining on them.

This is an example of what I'm trying to achieve

[image: example]

I can't really figure out what to search to find a shadertoy example or something that does this, but I've seen something similar before so I'm pretty sure it's possible.

To restate; I basically just want to remove part of the shader.

Not sure if using shaders is the best way to approach this, if there's another way then please let me know and I will remake the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily extend this to use any arbitrary position as the "light."

1. Declare a uniform buffer to store the current location and a radius.
2. If the distance from the given location to the current pixel is less than the radius squared return the current color.
3. Otherwise, return its greyscale.

   ```
   vec2 displacement = t - light_location;
   float distanceSq = (displacement.x * displacement.x + displacement.y * displacement.y)
   float radiusSq = radius * radius;
   if(distanceSq < radiusSq) {
       fragColor = texture(uTexture);
   } else {
       float sum = texture(uTexture).r;
       sum += texture(uTexture).g;
       sum += texture(uTexture).b;
       float grey = sum / 3.0f;
      fragColor = vec4(grey, grey, grey, 1.0f);
   }
   ```